# Attachment page url wrong on custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have modified 2017 WordPress theme to suit my needs. I have replaced the default post type with my own "blog_post" type. Everything works fine until I try to insert media image (through post editing GUI) into the post. I want the user to be redirected to the attachment page if he click on the image thus I select "link to: attachment page". The problem is that inserted URL is wrong.

The inserted url has following structure: http://mydomain/image_name/, if I click on the image it says page not found. If I submit post and then edit it, it now says that the image links to the custom URL. If I check the attachment page from drop down URL gets fixed to the correct one:  http://mydomain/blog_post/2017/post_name/image_name/

I have custom permalink structured as: */%year%/%postname%/*

How can I fix the link inserted in the first place to be in correct format? It is really tedious to edit all images on each posted post just to fix wrong urls.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset permalink structured, it'll work for you